# Disable or Hide CutomTask Pane close button VSTO addin word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, customtaskpane

I am using a CutomTask Pane in Word as an C# .NET ADDIN.
The custom task pane has a close button(X) at the right corner.
I need to not allow the user to close the Task Pane or disable the Close button(X) .
Can anyone have any idea ?
Is there any way to trap the close(X) button and prevent user from closing it ?

or some event through i can identify that user has click on button(x) of Task Pane.

[image: as shown in image i need to remove or disable button(x) from task pane]

Comment: There's nothing the Word or VSTO or Office APIs that enable a developer to access this functionality. Perhaps something in the Windows APIs...